# SparkFiles - path not found

Tags: pyspark

Please, can you help me with this question below? The image with the error is available in the question.

I use Azure databricks for data engineering. Running the same code in *databricks community* runs without error, but in Azure returns the error that path was not found. Has anyone been through this situation?
I'm using sparkfiles.

```
cnae = 'https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/cnae/subclasses'
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(cnae)

cnaeDF = spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("file://"+SparkFiles.get("subclasses"))
```

[pixel raster: rendered error message & stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfEfm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug on runtime 10 as `spark.sparkContext.addFile(cnae)` add it to local storage:

```
/local_disk0/spark-f1411c54-0a2e-4138-a0ed-c2e6bbfe5ca4/userFiles-7616de8f-3e03-493c-89e6-50fa1f7324ca/subclasses
```

but `SparkFiles.get("subclasses")` want to read it from dbfs storage (I tried to add it all possible ways)...

but when magic command is run:

```
%sh
cp -r /local_disk0/spark-f1411c54-0a2e-4138-a0ed-c2e6bbfe5ca4 /dbfs/local_disk0/
```

then it is possible to read it without problem

Comment: hello Hubert Dudek, I couldn't redo the command to copy the file to directory, was the command done in a notebook cell?

Comment: yes but with %sh and folder I got with SparkFiles.getRootDirectory( )but I think it is temporary solution as it doesn't work correctly. Maybe better just import requests and do requests.get ?

Comment: very strange, the same code used in the Databricks community doesn't generate errors, but in azure it doesn't run. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: that's why it is a bug, difference is that community version have limited access to file system which seems to be advantage here... I plan to send it directly to databricks as I test it and it is not working correctly. Most funny is that I planed to implement it tomorrow for some client so will go with requests instead

Comment: please update me through this forum. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, could you give me the claim number so I can follow up?

Comment: I just opened topic about it but no answers https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001XD3pjCAD/sparkfiles-strange-behavior-on-azure-databricks-runtime-10